# Libgdx preferences cause lag

Tags: java, libgdx, save, preferences

so I started using preferences to save my objects positions (about 800 ints).

When I press new game in my app it's ok, runs smoothly but after few times going back to menu, then load back to game, it starts to lag, or starts to work too fast.

What could be the causes of these app actions? Do I need to dispose a screen when i switch to another? Or something just gets stuck on looping when loading preferences?

Comment: Did you try removing preferences and then test app? I don't think this probles is caused by preferences.

Comment: My fault. Turns out every time i go to menu and back to game it creates a new class again at that means again creates objects so every time objects doubles and doubles and it goes to 3000+ objects not 400